# The series $2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+11x^4+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, power-series

It occurred to me to ask whether the power series whose coefficients are the primes has non-zero radius of convergence, and if so, what kind of function it produces.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) has some bounds on the $n$th prime number, and assuming that they're correct, we eventually have (where the $^2$ indicates iteration):

$$p_n<n\log n + n\log^2n=n\log (n\log n)$$

Now, we have eventually $n < n\log n < n^2$, the left inequality as $\log n > 1$ and the right because $\log n < n$, and both logs and $n$th roots are increasing, so we conclude:

$$\sqrt[n]{\log n} < \sqrt[n]{\log(n\log n)} < \sqrt[n]{\log(n^2)}=\sqrt[n]2\sqrt[n]{\log n}$$

And as $1<\log n<n^2$, we have $\sqrt[n]{\log n}\to 1$ and so $\sqrt[n]{\log(n\log n)}\to 1$. So the series with $n$th coefficient $n\log (n\log n)$ has radius of convergence $1$. Since it's coefficient-wise greater than the series with prime coefficients, the latter has radius of convergence at least $1$.

Is this reasoning correct? Did I interpret the upper bound on $p_n$ correctly? (ie. is it exact, like I think it is, or is it just asymptotically true in some sense?) If I'm right, then what's known about the function $f(x)=\sum p_n x^n, x\in \mathbb C$? Otherwise, where did I go wrong, and is the radius of convergence actually non-zero?

Comment: The radius of convergence is indeed $1$, and your reasoning is correct, although a little more complicated than needed. We know $\sqrt[n]{n^k} \to 1$, so with a bound of $1 \leqslant p_n \leqslant 2n^2$ (or $2^{123456789}n^{987654321}$ if we are magnanimous) we find $\sqrt[n]{p_n} \to 1$. I can't say much about the function whose Taylor series that is (beyond the obvious).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, duh, I didn't even think of looking for a simpler upper bound. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually, where *did* you find that upper bound? I can't figure it out. Any nice elementary upper bounds on the $n$th prime whose $n$th roots tend to $1$?

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/xlR1dN2) is a plot for the first 1000 terms of the series. It looks like [this](http://imgur.com/Ew2p2UL) for the first 100 terms, so it seems to be fairly stable.

Comment: I just pulled it out of the prime number theorem. That $p_n \sim n\log n$ certainly implies $p_n \leqslant 2n^2$ for all large enough $n$, we know it also holds for small $n$ (although we don't need that for the radius of convergence). Of course $p_n \leqslant 2n\log n$ for large enough $n$, which also immediately follows from $p_n\sim n\log n$, works the same way. My point was primarily that you don't need to be concerned with whether $n\log n + n\log \log n$ is an exact upper bound, a much cruder bound suffices. And although I haven't looked, I would expect that a bound with a faster growth

Comment: like $n^2$, or some higher exponent, would be easier to prove, if you don't have the prime number theorem to give you the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Any conjecture for a sum of this series?  I am not aware of any.

Comment: Try out summation by parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed
$$
n< p_n<n \log (n\log n),
$$
implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n^{1/n}=1,
$$
which by the root test implies that the radius of convergence of the power series is equal to $1$.